# why my ball is blurry when I started the game in xna 4.0?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am using this code, but I still dont figure out why the ball is blurry when I started the game, can someone help me??, I just tryingto to me the ball when the user click but I dont know why It is blurry, I still cheking the code, please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Critters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D ball;


        Vector2 playerPosition;
        Vector2 direction;
        Vector2 destination;        
        float speed;

        float playerPosX;
        float playerPosY;


        MouseState oldState;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 700;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();
            Window.Title = "Darrells Game";


            playerPosY = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 10 * 8;
            playerPosX = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2;
            playerPosition = new Vector2(playerPosX, playerPosY);
            destination = playerPosition;


            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);



            ball = Content.Load<Texture2D>("orb");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content her
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();


            if (Vector2.DistanceSquared(destination, playerPosition) >= speed * speed)
            {
                MovePlayer();
            }
            else
            {
                playerPosition = destination;
            }



            MouseState leftState = Mouse.GetState();
            MouseState rightState = Mouse.GetState();             

            if ((leftState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && rightState.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed))
            {
                int mouseX = leftState.X;
                int mouseY = leftState.Y;
                destination = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);
                speed = 8.0f;

            }

            else if (leftState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                int mouseX = leftState.X;
                int mouseY = leftState.Y;
                destination = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);
                speed = 2.0f;
            }


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


            spriteBatch.Begin();
            DrawPlayer();
            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        private void DrawPlayer()
        {

            Vector2 textureCentre = new Vector2(ball.Width / 2, ball.Height / 2);

            spriteBatch.Draw(ball, playerPosition, null, Color.White, 0f, textureCentre, 0.8f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

        }

        private void MovePlayer()
        {

            {
                direction = destination - playerPosition;
                direction.Normalize();
                playerPosition += direction * speed;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: don't bother making the playerPosX and playerPosY float variables. Just set playerPosition.X and playerPosition.Y directly. You could also combine speed and direction into one Velocity vector, whose direction is 'direction' and whose length is 'speed'. These are just small things to reduce code clutter. I can't find anything other than the scale issue that was already addressed that would make it blurry. Perhaps provide some images?

Comment: Is it any less blurry in fullscreen mode?

Comment: @A-Type, creepybrain  just another question please I am trying to make a penalty shootout game I make the goalkeeper a rectangle for the collision of the ball, if the ball intersect the goalkeeper its not a goal, but if the ball was inside the area of the line Its a goal, how did you do this kind of game??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your draw call:

```
spriteBatch.Draw
(
   ball,                   // texture
   playerPosition,         // location
   null,                   // source rect
   Color.White,            // color
   0f,                     // rotation
   textureCentre,          // origin
   0.8f,                   // scale
   SpriteEffects.None,     // effects
   1f                      // layerDepth
);
```

You have set the scale to `0.8f`. This will draw your texture smaller than it really is, which will involve some 'blurring'. Changing the scale value to `1f` should get rid of any blurring caused by scaling.

EDIT: If the blurring you mean is the flickering that happens before you have clicked, that is caused by having a destination that is exactly equal to the current location. Your `MovePlayer` method then causes the current position to become `(NaN, NaN)`:

```
// before the user has clicked, destination == playerPosition
private void MovePlayer()
{
   direction = destination - playerPosition;  // direction = (0, 0)
   direction.Normalize();                     // direction = (NaN, NaN)
   playerPosition += direction * speed;       // playerPosition = (NaN, NaN)
}
```

A quick fix for this would be in your `Initialize` method, change the line:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
   ...

   // change this
   mDestination = mPlayerPosition;

   // to this
   mDestination = mPlayerPosition + new Vector2(1, 1);
```

Comment: I changed and It still do some blurring, I dont know what to do? thanks for answering

Comment: @GeorgeBecj k, I added more to the answer

Comment: just another question please I am trying to make a penalty shootout game I make the goalkeeper a rectangle for the collision of the ball, if the ball intersect the goalkeeper its not a goal, but if the ball was inside the area of the line Its a goal, how did you do this kind of game??

Comment: @GeorgeBecj use a rectangle for the goal as well; if the ball hits the goal before it hits the goalie, it's a goal. You might want to open a new question for this, although try to be specific. "How do you do this kind of game" is a bit too vague.